# Change a DCOM application's identity with a script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, dcom

I have a Powershell script to set up a WS2012 web server with no user interaction. The only thing I can't do in the script is to change the identity of a DCOM application. Or, more specifically, I cannot set the password of the user.

I know it's a registry key trick, but the only thing I can achieve is:

```
$keypath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{key-ID}"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $keypath -Name RunAs -Value domain\user
```

Which creates a `REG_SZ` called `RunAs` with the value `domain\user`, so it works. Via UI, navigating to that DCOM application the identity has been set correctly, but not its password, and I cannot find how to do it.

Any hints?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure any more if that script doesn't work, even though no password has been set. I'm working on it and I will let you know, just for possible future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the password this way. But you can set the username and password using DComPerm, which is available in the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), but only in source form (C++) in the directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\com\fundamentals\dcom\dcomperm
```

You will have to compile the source, or find a binary version somewhere on the net.

The commandline for dcomperm.exe will then be:

```
dcomperm -runas {key-ID} domain\user password
```

Comment: Yeah, I already had that, but I didn't test it until now. It works, so +1 for you, thanks.